# INNER JOIN with json to get $numrows

Tags: php, sql, json, inner-join

I'm trying to get the JSON to echo out $nuM of comments of a post to auto update in the feed I have built. So I'm having to join my 'STREAMDATA table' and my 'STREAMDATA_COMMENTS' table.

I believe I am on the right track. However, I think my query is wrong as it is outputting no data of the two tables even been joined.

STREAMDATA has a row streamitem_id which is the main post created by the user

Structure -> streamitem_id | streamitem_type_id | streamitem_creator | streamitem_target | streamitem_timestamp | streamitem_conten

STREAMDATA_COMMENTS has a row that corresponds with the above  table called comment_streamitem which matches to the streamitem_id.

STRUCTURE -> comment_id | comment_poster | comment_streamitem | comment_datetime | comment_content

Here is what I have so far.

```
$query = 'SELECT streamitem_id 
      FROM streamdata 
      LEFT JOIN streamdata_comments
      ON 
      streamitem_id = comment_streamitem';
$mysql_result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query);
$result = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mysql_result)) {
   $result[] = $row;
}
return json_encode($result);
//json_encode()
```

UPDATE
This is an error on my part. I had put RETURN instead of ECHO. It is now working correctly.

Comment: What happens if you run that query directly in a mysql prompt

Comment: `$nuM`? `$numrows`? I see no said variables here.

Comment: as said above, I don't know why you mention those variables. Now, if that is your full code, `return json_encode($result);` doing a return doesn't echo anything. How are you "echoing" those results? If not, then you need to replace "return" with "echo". You are using `mysqli_` to connect with, right?

Comment: Absolutely fantastic @Fred-ii- I didn't even notice I had put return and not echo. Its now working. Thanks so much. And sorry for the confusion. Thank you for your eagle eye.

Comment: great. if you want the question closed properly and marked as solved, let me know. I'll post an answer for it. and you're welcome

Comment: That would be fantastic, Thank you again for your help.

Comment: you're welcome, *cheers* it has been done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return json_encode($result);
```

Doing a return doesn't echo anything, unless you're using another function that contains an echo.

You need to replace "return" with "echo".

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php